# How to add the Excel file in the page on the Sharepoint 2010 foundation?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, excel, excel-web-access-webpart

I would like to insert an excel file into the Sharepoint page on SP 2010 foundation.

I saw we can export list to excel, so that I think maybe we can display the excel file in the page.

In SP 2010 Foundation, there do not exist the Excel Web Access. Do we have other solution for working with Excel in this environment?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with a power point presentation by using the PAGE VIEWER WEB PART.

Displaying it as a web page and placing the link to the xlsx workbook.

The excel web part is better tho.

Comment: I think your way doesn't work like we thought. The browser will download the file instead of displaying file in browser even I set the Browser File Handling is Permissive.